# Delphi unexpected behavior of override

Tags: delphi, theory

Turn on your time machine and visit ancient times: It's Delphi and it is 2007.

For our beginners handbook I write down some basic things of programming (with Delphi). Doing so I found a quirk, I don't quite understand. To demonstrate inheritance I wrote a base class and a heir of it. A function is reintroduced, the other is overridden by the Heir.

```
unit UOverride;
interface
type
Base = class(TObject)
  strict private
    const
      CName: String = 'Base-Class';
      CMaxim: String = 'Somebody set up us the bomb.';
  public
    function GetName(): String; virtual;
    function GetMaxim(): String; virtual;

end;

Heir = class(Base)
  strict private
    const
      CName: String = 'Heir-Class';
      CMaxim: String = 'All your Base are belong to us!';
  public
    function GetName(): String; reintroduce;
    function GetMaxim(): String; override;
    function GetBaseName(): String;
    function GetBaseMaxim():String;
end;

implementation
{ Base }
function Base.GetMaxim: String;
begin
  Result := CMaxim;
end;

function Base.GetName: String;
begin
  Result := CName;
end;

{ Heir }
function Heir.GetMaxim: String;
begin
  Result := CMaxim;
end;

function Heir.GetName: String;
begin
  Result := CName;
end;

end.
```

So when I create an object of Base and call the too functions, it works as expected:

- `GetName()` => *Base-Class*  and
- `GetMaxim()` =>*Somebody set up us the bomb.*

Same for an instance of Heir:

- `GetName()` => *Heir-Class*  and
- `GetMaxim()` =>*All your Base are belong to us!*

Now I cast my instance of Heir to Base and call both functions again.

- `GetName()` => *Base-Class* which leaves no questions and
- `GetMaxim()` =>*All your Base are belong to us!* as expected, because it is overriden by Heir.

I added two more functions to Heir just out of curiosity.

```
function Heir.GetBaseName: String;
begin
  Result := inherited GetName();
end;

function Heir.GetBaseMaxim: String;
begin
  Result := inherited GetMaxim();
end;
```

I expect the `GetBaseName()` to give me *Base-Class* - so it happens. For `GetBaseMaxim()` I'm not sure. In my opinion three things are possible

1. It doesn't compile and throws an error or
2. It runs and will fail with an exception (because inherited function is overridden or
3. most expected it gives me `GetMaxim()` from Heir telling me *All your Base are belong to us!*.

Neither happens! I get *Somebody set up us the bomb.* from my base class?! Why? I thought the function is overriden by Heir! It is not a big deal, but I don't quite understand that behavior, because it does not work as I expected. Any explanations out there?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: If you call `inherited something`, you get the `something` of the direct ancestor, in this case of the base class. I wouldn't have expected anything else. Note that `inherited` bypasses the virtual mechanism. It must. Otherwise, you would always get the most derived `something`, and that is exactly what you don't want, if you use `inherited`.

Comment: The reason why I ask to see complete code is that it's hard to follow excerpts, there is code missing, declarations, calling code. A simple complete console app removes all doubt.

Comment: But I did an override of GetMaxim() in the object created of Heir. So the function implemented by Base shouldn't be available anymore in the specific object of Heir - at least in the way I understood 'override'. Maybe I missunderstood. It was just unexpected (for me).

Comment: Why must you describe code. Can't we see it?

Comment: Here is a complete project [link]https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7A198E46906D39B3!123&authkey=!ANgcLGdRYC3Q5Es&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: No, please add a [mcve] to the question. Just a 50 line console app that uses Writeln to emit output.

Comment: Code is not available *in* an object. It is there, and if you call `inherited`, you call it directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Inherited` gives non-virtual dispatch to the ancestor function, and that's exactly what you observed. Most often, the function it's used from in the descendant class has the same name as the inherited function being invoked, but as you've demonstrated, that custom is not required. You can non-virtually invoke any inherited method from anywhere in the descendant class.

Comment: So it was just a missunderstanding of how the concept is implemented. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes - it looks as though you were expecting `inherited` to yield the method in the 'heir'.  I can sort of see how you might think that, but it means the opposite - it is the method provided for the 'heir' by the ancestor.

Answer (score 5):

This is nothing special. With `inherited` you request the implementation of the base class.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Methods#Inherited) says:

> If inherited is followed by the name of a member, it represents a
>   normal method call or reference to a property or field, except that
>   the search for the referenced member begins with the immediate
>   ancestor of the enclosing method's class